# include custom Javascript file in catalog search frontend Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, frontend, catalogsearch, requirejs

i have a custom module with frontend custom js located in `app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/web/js/preorder.js` that i need to include it in catalogsearch frontend, for now my requirejs-config.js look like this:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer': {
                'Namespace_Module/js/swatch-renderer-mixin': true
            }
        }
    },
    map: {
        '*': {
            preorder: 'Namespace_Module/js/preorder',,
        catalogAddToCart: "Namespace_Module/js/catalog-add-to-cart",
        "Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart": "Namespace_Module/js/catalog-add-to-cart"
        }
    }
};
```

i need to add that **preorder** in catalogsearch frontend, how can i add it to catalog search layout?

Comment: Do you want to add js in catalogsearch result? can you tell me in which xml or page you want to add

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. yes

Comment: You can add using catalogsearch template file, require(["jquery","preorder"],function($,preorder){});

Answer (score 1):

Add below line in `catalogsearch_result_index.xml` before body tag.

```
<link src="Namespace_Module::js/slider/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js"/>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the [search results template](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/view/frontend/templates/advanced/result.phtml) (copy the file to your theme) add the JS using require, it is no longer best practice to add JS via the XML.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    // components initialized on the element defined by selector
    "<element_selector>": {
        "<js_component1>": ...,
        "<js_component2>": ...
    },
    // components initialized without binding to an element
    "*": {
        "<js_component3>": ...
    }
}
</script>
```

More info can be found on the [dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html).